# Cant control OpenManipulator on Turtlebot3

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, manipulator, turtlebot3

I'm using the OpenManipulator on the Turtlebot3 together with Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS2 Humble.
When I start the bringup for the manipulator it looks like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ros2 launch turtlebot3_manipulation_bringup hardware.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2024-02-13-19-14-57-372951-ubuntu-1220
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-1]: process started with pid [1223]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [1225]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [1227]
[INFO] [ld08_driver-4]: process started with pid [1229]
[ros2_control_node-1] [WARN] [1707851701.028090660] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.030773826] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.058046400] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.065202308] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Succeeded to open port
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.072887308] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Succeeded to set baudrate
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.081206937] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: OpenCR Model Number 20480
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.084141178] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Connected manipulator
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.086193789] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Connected wheels
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.086533993] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem'
[ros2_control_node-1] [WARN] [1707851701.087190937] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated]: Automatic activation of all hardware components will not be supported in the future anymore. Use hardware_spawner instead.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.087371048] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.087426363] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.087474974] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.087503585] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Ready for start
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851701.103077437] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Wait for IMU re-calibration
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [DynamixelSDKWrapper] [TxRxResult] There is no status packet!
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158223178] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158712159] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158810845] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158852734] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158884974] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_frame
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158916011] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158947900] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.158979382] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_right_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159010271] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment end_effector_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159040956] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159071530] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_right_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159100937] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159131011] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159194067] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159226900] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159256252] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159286178] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link5
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159316141] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1707851701.159828456] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[ld08_driver-4] /dev/ttyACM0    OpenCR Virtual ComPort in FS Mode
[ld08_driver-4] /dev/ttyUSB0    CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ld08_driver-4] FOUND LDS-02
[ld08_driver-4] LDS-02 started successfully 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.137664547] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Joints and wheels torque ON
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.157505917] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Set profile acceleration and velocity to joints
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.195505232] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Set profile acceleration and velocity to gripper
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.220545343] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Set goal current value to gripper
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.239520324] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: System starting
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.242533472] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'TurtleBot3ManipulationSystem'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.272584676] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.273230398] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.273425065] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Start to read wheels and manipulator states
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.282993880] [turtlebot3_manipulation]: Start to write wheels and manipulator commands
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.369719639] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1707851704.439436565] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.443905139] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851704.444297769] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1707851704.601681287] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 1227]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [1276]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [1278]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [1280]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [1282]
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851707.773806896] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'diff_drive_controller'
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1707851708.045779581] [spawner_diff_drive_controller]: Loaded diff_drive_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851708.257852396] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'diff_drive_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851708.466989044] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'gripper_controller'
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1707851708.478655396] [spawner_diff_drive_controller]: Configured and activated diff_drive_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851708.582573618] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'arm_controller'
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1707851708.775381562] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Loaded gripper_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [WARN] [1707851708.816909285] [arm_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851708.856514210] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'gripper_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851708.856862710] [gripper_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20Hz.
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1707851709.009955470] [spawner_arm_controller]: Loaded arm_controller
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 1282]
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1707851709.075054840] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Configured and activated gripper_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.077328081] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'arm_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.077820507] [arm_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.077943470] [arm_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.078002951] [arm_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.085479877] [arm_controller]: Controller state will be published at 200.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.101699192] [arm_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.334179488] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'imu_broadcaster'
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1707851709.339488895] [spawner_arm_controller]: Configured and activated arm_controller
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 1276]
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1707851709.630353506] [spawner_imu_broadcaster]: Loaded imu_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1707851709.642139803] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'imu_broadcaster'
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1707851709.762841488] [spawner_imu_broadcaster]: Configured and activated imu_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 1278]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 1280]
```

Then I start `ros2 launch turtlebot3_manipulation_moveit_config servo.launch.py`
and `ros2 run turtlebot3_manipulation_teleop turtlebot3_manipulation_teleop`.

After the moveit command it looks like this:

```
christian@Chris-PC:~$ ros2 launch turtlebot3_manipulation_moveit_config servo.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/christian/.ros/log/2024-02-13-20-15-21-893695-Chris-PC-4944
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [servo_node_main-1]: process started with pid [4945]
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851722.131933940] [moveit_servo.servo_node]: Intra-process communication is disabled, consider enabling it by adding: 
[servo_node_main-1] extra_arguments=[{'use_intra_process_comms' : True}]
[servo_node_main-1] to the Servo composable node in the launch file
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.136750545] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0037646 seconds
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.136770739] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'turtlebot3_manipulation'...
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851722.210949619] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link end_effector_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.476904230] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic '/joint_states'
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.480997099] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.481009618] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.481732693] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[servo_node_main-1] [INFO] [1707851722.481949245] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on '/servo_node/publish_planning_scene'
```

Then I can move the base of the Turtlebot without any problems, but as soon as I start moving the manipulator I get errors like this:

```
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851733.941429353] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.041285092] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.141810070] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.241289971] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.341275063] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.441300931] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.541911883] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.641193613] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.741929769] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.841255899] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851734.941284766] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.041930688] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.141185971] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.241931314] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.341282696] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.441277423] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.541928217] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.607629891] [moveit_servo.utilities]: Very close to a singularity, emergency stop
[servo_node_main-1] [ERROR] [1707851735.607652532] [moveit_servo.servo_calcs]: Halting for collision!
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.641309497] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
[servo_node_main-1] [WARN] [1707851735.741280457] [moveit_collision_detection.collision_common]: Objects in collision (printing 1st of 1 pairs): link2, link4
```

But there is no collision anywhere, so I dont know why I get this error. When I push the s key on my keyboard the manipulator moves into an 90 degree angle.
I dont know if the error message from the bringup has to do something with it. Maybe someone knows what to do here?
Best regards.